# How to divide two unumpy arrays produced via uncertainties package while avoiding "division by zero"

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, numpy-ndarray, divide-by-zero, uncertainty

I have two unumpy arrays in the form of mean and std.

```
import numpy as np
from uncertainties import unumpy

A = unumpy.uarray(np.array([2,4,6,8,10]), np.array([0.2,0.3,0.1,0.5,0.3]))
B = unumpy.uarray(np.array([6,10,15,0,40]), np.array([0.1,0.2,0.1,np.nan,0.3]))
A/B
```

Now, I would like to calculate A/B but I am receiving "division by zero". However, I would like to do the division only for those values whose B is not 0 +/- nan. In the exception, I would simply like to leave the division result as nan +/- nan or simply remove them all together.

Note:
If these were simple arrays rather than uarrays, I know how to use `np.divide` or `np.where`.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a mask to remove them altogether from the array using `unumpy.nominal_values`. and checking if the nominal value is `0`.

---

```
m = unumpy.nominal_values(B) != 0

A[m] / B[m]
```

```
array([0.3333333333333333+/-0.033793125168323446,
       0.4+/-0.031048349392520047, 0.4+/-0.007180219742846007,
       0.25+/-0.0077308230480331135], dtype=object)
```

---

If you want to mask your arrays based on a condition for your deviations, you can similarly use `unumpy.std_devs`

```
>>> unumpy.std_devs(B)
array([0.1, 0.2, 0.1, nan, 0.3])
```